# Why my BigDecimal calculations in JavaScript is not working?

Tags: javascript, dojo, bigdecimal

This code is not working:

```
dojo.require("com.ibm.team.workitem.shared.common.BigDecimal");
var BigDecimal= com.ibm.team.workitem.shared.common.BigDecimal;
var vlr1 = new BigDecimal('88.66');
var vlr2 = new BigDecimal('44.2844835221463');
var vlr_result = vlr1.multiply(vlr2);
```

When creating the vlr2 variable, nothing happens, neither an error.
What am I doing wrong?

How is the correct way to create the BigDecimal value with the number 44.2844835221463?

Thanks in advance.
Luiz Cesar.

Comment: What does "nothing happens" mean?

Comment: Hi Luiz. Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you try to `console.log(vlr_result);` ?

Comment: "nothing happens" means that nothing is outputed in the console.

Comment: Yes, I used the console.log(vlr_result); but nothing is outputed.

Comment: I think the problem is with com.ibm.team.workitem.shared.common.BigDecimal class that does not support some functions. By the way, I solve the problem using float values instead of BigDecimal objects.